# How can I find the end position of enumerator?

Tags: c++-cli

How can I find the end position of enumerator? For this enumerator I didn't see any atEnd method in the documentation.

```
SortedSet<Button ^>::Enumerator^ enumer = btnSet->GetEnumerator();
enumer->atEnd();
```

my error

```
error 'atEnd' : is not a member of 'System::Collections::Generic::SortedSet<T>::Enumerator'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your intention to write a loop like `while (enumer != btnSet->end())`, as is common with many C++ iterators?

You can check if an enumerator is not yet at the end, by checking the return value of [`MoveNext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321013.aspx), so the loop would be this:

```
SortedSet<Button^>::Enumerator^  enumer = btnSet->GetEnumerator();
while (enumer->MoveNext()) {
    Button^ btn = enumer->Current;
    // do stuff 
}
```

You could also iterate over the collection using a [`for each`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202%28VS.80%29.aspx) loop, which looks a bit cleaner:

```
for each (Button^ btn in btnSet) {
    // do stuff
}
```